# Search JS Object for Value

Tags: javascript, loops, javascript-objects

Say I have an object:

```
userInfo
```

And I want to search each node of userInfo to see if the key 'username' has a value equal to foo.

```
userInfo[x].username == "foo"
```

Is there a better way of doing the following?

```
var matchFound = false;

for (var i = 0, len = userInfo.length; i < len; i++)
     matchFound = userInfo[i].username == "foo";
```

Comment: This won't work.  The value of matchFound is constantly overwritten.

Comment: Also, what's the point of the `? true : false` part?  `userInfo[i].username == "foo"` already evaluates to true or false.

Comment: technically, you are cycling through `Array` with `Objects` inside. There are not much _better_ ways of doing it. @awm, i assume he shows us pseudo-code.

Comment: I fixed that. I just threw this example together really quick. The question is more about how to search the object and if there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a better (more efficient) way without introducing another data structure. The answer really depends on your usage but you could do a few different things:

1. Create separate 'indexes' using hashes. These structures would map keys to the items or the index in the source array. JavaScript objects/hashes support key based lookup and should be efficient.

   ```
   userinfo[x].username = "foo";
   // Index the objects
   usersByName = {};
   usersByName["foo"] = userinfo[x];
   // -- OR -- index the array indices
   var usersByName["foo"] = x;
   // Test for key
   "foo" in usersByName; // true
   ```

   You'll have to put in a little more work to maintain consistency between the index and the source array. It's probably best to wrap both in another object to manage the contents of both. This approach is nice if there are multiple fields that you want to look objects up by.
2. If you don't care about the order of the collection you could just change the whole thing to a hash and index by username

   ```
   var userinfo = {};
   userinfo["foo"] = {username: "foo", firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar"};
   ```

One thing to think about, though, is if the efficiency gains are going to outweigh the increased code complexity of maintaining indexes. If you aren't doing a lot of searches and you don't have tons of items in the userinfo collection it may make more sense to just write a general use searching function or use a library like what Philip Schweiger was mentioning.

```
function findObjectByAttribute (items, attribute, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i][attribute] === value) {
      return items[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
var userinfo = [];
userinfo[0] = {username: "foo"};
console.log(findObjectByAttribute(userinfo, "username", "foo"));
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for the ternary operator, consider the following:

```
var matchFound = false;

for (var i = 0, len = userInfo.length; i < len; i++)
{
    matchFound = userInfo[i].username == "foo";
    if(matchFound){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah true, but the nature of my question was more about finding a more efficient way of searching the object (if one exists).

Answer (score 3):

The underscore JS library has some handy methods to work with data collections - for instance, the [select method](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#select)

Implementing it would like like this:

```
var userInfo = {
    'x':{
        username: "foo",
        password:'dlji'
    },
    'y':{
        username: "bar" ,
        password:'adfasf'
    },
    'z': {
        username: 'foo',
        password:'d3alj4i'
    }
};

var found = _.select(userInfo, function(node){

    return node.username === "foo"
}); 
console.dir (found);
```

Underscore isn't very large, and while you can do this in native JS too, I think it does a good job implementing the solutions you'd come up with on your own. Basically, it gives you a lot of the JS features you'd think should be there anyway.